# Distinguishing between Japanese number formats

Tags: .net, string, string-comparison

In .NET, I need (if possible) to distinguish between different types of Japanese number strings.

In Japanese number strings can be written in different ways, e.g for `"1"` there is `"1"`, `"ⅰ"`, `"Ⅰ"`, `"①"` in half-width characters.

I need to compare strings like `"MyString1"` and `"MyString①"`, and for obvious reasons they are not equal.
I am wondering if there is a way to automatically change `"①"` type characters to `"1"` automatically?

EDIT

I know that the obvious answer would be to make a list of all possible "①" type characters (there is a finite number of those) and replace them in the target string. But that's not a very "nice" way of going about this in my opinion, nor is it very robust... so if there is a generic way I'd much rather use that.

EDIT

Apologies, I previously wrote that bot `"①"` and `"1"` are considered numbers, but they are not. IsNumeric `"①"` comes up as false. So I guess there might actually be no way at all to switch from one to the other apart from using a straight substitution.

Comment: Have you looked at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a7zyyk0c.aspx and playing with CultureInfo?

Comment: @Richard I was going to suggest the same and just tried that, but `Compare` returns `"1"` and `"①"` are different, even case insensitive in the "ja-JP" culture.

Comment: @Richard Thanks for the link. Strings and CultureInfo is really something I am not familiar with, so not sure if I'll be able to use it though...

Comment: @abatishchev I have tried `Equals` with all three types of cutural comparisons, but no joy.

Comment: Are you also saying you'd like `MyStringii` and `MyString2' to be equal? That seems to be a recipe for trouble to me.

Comment: There wouldn't be anything built in to .NET that can do this, even though they both may mean '1' they are still different characters. Intercepting the user entering the numbers and modifying them to a particular format may be a good idea?

Comment: @KenY-N That's a good point. Although in this case I know that the number would be a the end the string and would always be in the `"①"` format

Comment: @Tyriar OK, Well I think I'll just go with the string substitution approach then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[fileformat.info](http://fileformat.info/) tells me that [circled digits](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2460/index.htm) can be decomposed into regular digits. Poking at this [in ideone](http://ideone.com/QhSupD) shows that the [normalization forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.normalizationform.aspx) that will achieve that in .NET are KC or KD:

```
var one  = "①";
Console.WriteLine(one);

Console.WriteLine(one.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC)); // ①
Console.WriteLine(one.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD)); // ①

Console.WriteLine(one.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKC)); // 1
Console.WriteLine(one.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKD)); // 1
```

That said, there is a caveat in that normalizing a string might also mangle other characters you want to remain as-is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since I want to avoid mangling the string as you said I am looping through and only changing characters which come up as numeric using `Char.getNumericValue()` as I said in my answer. I'm gonna accept this as the answer though, because I think it's way better than mine :)

Answer (score 1):

OK, playing around with stuff I found that I can convert "①" to it's numeric value (`"1"`) using `Char.GetNumericValue()` which is quite interesting because `IsNumeric("①")` comes up as `False`.

And this also seems to work for "ⅰ" and "Ⅰ" (not letters but the Japanese number format for "1")

I wish I understood culture changes more...

Comment: This is probably a factoid buried somewhere deep in the bowels of the Unicode spec. fileformat.info lists some sort of "numeric equivalent" for characters, which must be what `GetNumericValue()` returns. However, the fact a character does have a numeric equivalent probably doesn't imply that the character itself is a numeric digit. I'm guessing `IsNumeric()` is the same as saying "is the character in `Nd`" (*Numeric, digit*), however circled digits are `No` (*Numeric, other*)

Comment: Thanks a lot for you explanations. These type of characters are usually used for bulleting lists, so that must be why. Other strange stuff is that although in western culture you'd use "i" or "I" to bullet a list, the Japanese "ⅰ" and "Ⅰ" are different. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Also, according to the documentation, `Char.IsNumber()` should recognize the same characters as `Char.GetNumericValue()` as numeric, so you might use that instead of `IsNumeric()`. (Can't find where that function comes from, is it a VB thing?)

Comment: Yes, `IsNumeric()` is a leftover from VB6. I know it's bad practice, but it's just easy to use (and a bit dangerous sometimes). Thanks for the tip on `IsNumber()`. `GetNumericValue()` appears to return `-1` for non-numeric values so I was using that. Of course, now I am wondering if there could ever be a non-numeric char with value `-1`. I'll use `IsNumber()` to be on the safe side and then `GetNumericValue()` for concatenation purposes. Thanks!